# Powershell Timespan inconsistent

Tags: powershell, timespan

At the start of my powershell script, I have the following,

```
$scriptStarted = Get-Date
```

At the end of the script, I have

```
$scriptDuration = New-Timespan -Start $scriptStarted -End (Get-Date)
Write-Log -Message ("Script Complete. Script duration {0:hh} hours, {0:mm} minutes and {0:ss} seconds" -f $scriptDuration) -Path $logFile
```

I'm using the Write-Log from [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Write-Log-PowerShell-999c32d0/view/Discussions#content)

Inside the script, some sections are wrapped in their own duration finders. Here is an SQL Query example

```
$queryStarted = Get-Date
Write-Log "Executing Query..." -Path $logFile
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $dbConfig.Server -Database $dbConfig.Database -Credential $dbConfig.Credential -Query $dbConfig.Query -OutputSqlErrors $true | Out-File -FilePath $dbConfig.DataFile -Width 250
$queryDuration = New-Timespan -Start $transferStarted -End (Get-Date)
Write-Log -Message ("Query Complete.  Query duration {0:hh} hours, {0:mm} minutes and {0:ss} seconds" -f $queryDuration) -Path $logFile
```

My Issue is that the `$scriptDuration` is smaller than the `$queryDuration`

**Query Duration** VERBOSE: Query Complete.  Query duration 00 hours, 19 minutes and 10 seconds

**Script Duration** VERBOSE: Script Complete. Script duration 00 hours, 12 minutes and 43 seconds

The Script Duration should be longer than any sections inside it.

Comment: you are using `$queryDuration = New-Timespan -Start $transferStarted -End (Get-Date)` but the start time is stored in `$queryStarted = Get-Date`. so your start time is undefined. what do you get when you use the _correct_ $Var? [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mean you've got the wrong variable, so this:

```
$queryStarted = Get-Date
# ...
$queryDuration = New-Timespan -Start $transferStarted -End (Get-Date)
```

Should be this:

```
$queryStarted = Get-Date
# ...
$queryDuration = New-Timespan -Start $queryStarted -End (Get-Date)
```

But generally when people want to do this kind of thing, they use [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.0).

```
# Create new instance and start
$Stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

# Your code here

#Stop the Stopwatch
$Stopwatch.Stop()
"Duration {0:hh} hours, {0:mm} minutes and {0:ss} seconds" -f $Stopwatch.Elapsed
```

The resulting timespan object is at `$Stopwatch.Elapsed`. The stopwatch can be stopped, started, reset, etc. It handles all the math for you and knows how long it's been running.

Comment: In my defense, I went home sick that day.  So stopwatch.elapsed is just a timespan?

Comment: There's another concern, which is that `hh` formats hours that are not counted as part of a day.  Thus, if the script runs for 24 hours or longer, that is not represented in the string.  It would be prudent to either include days, or get the `TotalHours` property of the timespan and truncate its decimals.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint If there's a need to handle a script running more than 23 hours, you can include the `dd` days format or else use one of the standard formats: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings

Comment: Soz, should have accepted this 2 years ago >_<